# How to hardcode password in my shell script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a shell script which has Kerberos authentication at the beginning. How can I hard code the password in the shell script file?

#### myscript

```
kinit My_id@AD111.xxx.COM

echo 
hadoop fs -du -h /
echo
hadoop fs -du -h /home
echo
hadoop fs -du -h /mydata
```

I am running the script using:

```
sh /home/myscript.sh > /home/abc.log
```

Result:
The command gets into infinite loop and the enter password line will be directed to `abc.log`

Help me out how to add password below `kinit` in script file. "The password should be encrypted so as to hide it from others".

Comment: Instead of hard coding, use keytab file to store your password. You can then run `kinit -k -t my.keytab My_id@AD111.xxx.COM`.

Comment: Can I get the sample code to use keytab

Comment: I just updated my comment.

Comment: To create a keytab you can run `ktutil` and while in it `add_entry -password -p principal -k kvno -e enctype`. Check this out for more info on [ktutil](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ktutil).

Comment: apart from Keytab any other way to mention the password in script file itself?

Comment: If you are going to store the password encrypted or otherwise, there is no other way to pass it to kinit unless you write an `expect` script. That's not how things should be done. Store the password in keytab and let kinit handle it the way it was designed. It's as simple as adding `-k -t my.keytab` to your existing `kinit` command.

Comment: So I should run "ktutil" in root and it then type > entry1-my_password -p My_id@AD111.xxx.COM -k 1 -e RC4-HMAC > then enter the password > it shows the keytab file  and use that keytab in kinit right